# oData WCF service - hide an element

Tags: wcf, odata

I'm new to WCF. My web project has an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (aka EF edmx), which has the Entity Container Name `JobSystemEntities`.

I've created a simple oData WCF data service which uses `JobSystemEntities`, and it works great:

```
public class JobService : DataService<JobSystemEntities>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Jobs", EntitySetRights.ReadSingle);
    }
```

However, this exposes all of the properties on the Job. I would like to hide sensitive data, i.e. the Cost field/property/column of the Job table.

Comment: The easiest would be to just hide that attribute in your EF model - e.g. not ever use/show that. Could you do this? Or could you create a custom EF model just for your OData service, and hide that attribute from the "Jobs" entity in that custom model?

Comment: I use the Cost field in the website so it needs to be in the EF model. Your suggestion to create a second EF model for the oData service is possible, but I'm surprised there isn't another way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this a but late, but it might help others.

You can use the IgnoreProperties attribute http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.ignorepropertiesattribute.aspx on your class.

You will have to define a partial Job class in order to do this. Something in the lines of:

```
namespace DAL.Entities
{
    [IgnoreProperties("Cost")]
    public partial class Job
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works with Entity Framework as your data layer.  If you have something else then it should work fine.

Comment: I used it my self in a project recently, it worked fine with Entity Framework.

Comment: When it did not work for me I asked this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600037/add-ignoredatamemeber-to-specific-properties-in-a-generated-partial-class  The upshot was that it does not work for the POCO template.  (Maybe it does work for normal EF though.)

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to this. A good starting point is found here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/15/pre-filtering-and-shaping-odata-feeds-using-wcf-data-services-and-the-entity-framework-part-1.aspx

Basically you will need to separate the protected properties of an entity into a separate entity that is linked as a property of the other. Once that is done user a Query Interceptor to restrict when that protected entity can be viewed.

```
[QueryInterceptor("YourObjectsProtectedProperties")]
public Expression<Func<YourObjectsProtectedProperties, bool>> OnReadYourObjectsProtectedProperties()
{
if (ShowEntityToUser())
   return o => true == true;
return o => true == false;
}
```